# Using filepath.Glob in Go

Tags: regex, go, filepath

I have this bit while trying to understand filepath.Glob

```
for _, v := range ListofPaths{
    exists, _ := filepath.Glob(fmt.Sprintf("%s/*/%s", v, filename))
}
```

Which works for any path

```
ListofPathsPath/any/dot/thing/filename.ext
```

but not

```
ListofPathsPath/filename.ext
```

so from the above I need to match glob %s/%s or %s/*/%s

Is there a way to phrase this? I don't fully get the filepath.Match syntax yet and haven't found any comprehensive examples.

Comment: How about `**` instead of `*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really basic shell syntax, you can't do that.

You will have to either call glob twice or just use [`filepath.Walk`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk).